# How to stream a remote mp3 without using a full screen player? e.g. shoutcast

Tags: iphone, streaming, mp3

how do I play a remote .mp3 in an iPhone app with full control over the playback controls and visuals shown? I know MPMoviePlayerController can stream .mp3s but it takes over the whole screen.

If you could just point me in the direction of an appropriate guide or class reference that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think AVAudioPlayer supports streaming mp3s. From my experience, i am reasonably confident in saying that it only plays local files.

I have played remote mp3s using AVPlayer.

```
self.player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:fileURL];
//inits the AVPlayer object.
[player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
// You need to watch for for when the player obeject becomes ready to play, using key-value observation



-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if(object == player && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"])
    {
        playButton.enabled = YES;
        playButton.titleLabel.text = @"Play";
        ..... 
           //do whatever you need to do here to get the object ready to play.

    }
}
```

a simple [player play] will start playing the file.

```
//metadata is available at
player.currentItem.asset.commonMetadata
//and time played can be calculated by dividing x by y
    UInt64 x = self.player.currentTime.value; 
    int32_t y = self.player.currentTime.timescale;
    int secs = x/y;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use AVAudioPlayer and create your own controls.

I don't know if MPMediaPlayer can play a streamed mp3, but it can play local media in an "app" player instead of an "ipod" player (which takes over the screen).  MPMediaPlayer is similar to AVAudioPlayer in that you can play with or without any UI, which you can create.  Play, pause, stop, rewind, forward, etc.